# Change tkinter label text each time a button is pressed (for multiple buttons)

Tags: python-3.x, button, tkinter, label

I want to make a simple app that updates the label according to the button text when each button is pressed. suppose that  we have symbols, names, and atomic numbers of 118 elements.
button texts must consist of element symbols and when we press any button, how do we show the full name and atomic number of that element in the label text?
I wonder if I am proceeding correctly or is the algorithm I created wrong?
By the way, I have just started python programming,I would be glad if the codes you suggest
are not complicated, thanks in advance.

```
 from tkinter import *
 pencere = Tk()
 pencere.title("Elementler")
 pencere.state("zoomed")

elements_symbols = 

["H","He","Li","Be","B","C","N","O","F","Ne","Na","Mg","Al","Si","P",
"S","Cl","Ar",
"K","Ca","Sc","Ti","V","Cr","Mn","Fe","Co","Ni","Cu","Zn","Ga","Ge",
"As","Se","Br",
"Kr","Rb","Sr","Y","Zr","Nb","Mo","Tc","Ru","Rh","Pd","Ag","Cd",
"In","Sn","Sb","Te",
"I","Xe","Cs","Ba","La","Ce","Pr","Nd","Pm","Sm","Eu","Gd","Tb",
"Dy","Ho","Er","Tm",
"Yb","Lu","Hf","Ta","W","Re","Os","Ir","Pt","Au","Hg","Tl","Pb",
"Bi","Po","At","Rn",
"Fr","Ra","Ac","Th","Pa","U","Np","Pu","Am","Cm","Bk","Cf","Es",
"Fm","Md","No","Lr",
"Rf","Db","Sg","Bh","Hs","Mt","Ds","Rg","Cn","Nh","Fl","Mc","Lv",
"Ts","Og","None","None"]

elements_information = [["Hidrojen",1],["Helyum",2],["Lityum",3], 
["Berilyum",4],["Bor",5],["Karbon",6],["Azot",7],["Oksijen",8],["Flor",9],
["Neon",10],["Sodyum",11],["Magnezyum",12],["Alüminyum",13],["Silisyum",14], 
["Fosfor",15],["Kükürt",16],["Klor",17],
["Argon",18],["Potasyum",19],["Kalsiyum",20],["Skandiyum",21], 
["Titanyum",22],["Vanadyum",23],["Krom",24],["Mangan",25],
["Demir",26],["Kobalt",27],["Nikel",28],["Bakır",29],["Çinko",30], 
["Galyum",31],["Germanyum",32],["Arsenik",33],
["Selenyum",34],["Brom",35],["Kripton",36],["Rubidyum",37],["Stronsiyum",38], 
["Itriyum",39],["Zirkonyum",40],["Niobyum",41],
["Molibden",42],["Teknesyum",43],["Rutenyum",44],["Rodyum",45], 
["Paladyum",46],["Gümüş",47],["Kadmiyum",48],["Indiyum",49],
["Kalay",50],["Antimon",51],["Tellür",52],["İyot",53],["Ksenon",54], 
["Sezyum",55],["Baryum",56],["Lantan",57],
["Seryum",58],["Praseodim",59],["Neodimyum",60],["Prometyum",61], 
["Samaryum",62],["Evropiyum",63],["Gadolinyum",64],
["Terbiyum",65],["Disprozyum",66],["Holmiyum",67],["Erbiyum",68], 
["Tulyum",69],["İterbiyum",70],["Lutesyum",71],["Hafniyum",72],
["Tantal",73],["Tungsten",74],["Renyum",75],["Osmiyum",76],["İridyum",77], 
["Platin",78],["Altın",79],["Civa",80],["Talyum",81],
["Kurşun",82],["Bizmut",83],["Polonyum",84],["Astatin",85],["Radon",86], 
["Fransiyum",87],["Radyum",88],["Aktinyum",89],
["Toryum",90],["Protaktinyum",91],["Uranyum",92],["Neptünyum",93], 
["Plütonyum",94],["Amerikyum",95],["Küriyum",96],
["Berkelyum",97],["Kaliforniyum",98],["Aynştaynyum",99],["Fermiyum",100], 
["Mendelevyum",101],["Nobelyum",102],["Lavrensiyum",103],
["Rutherfordiyum",104],["Dubniyum",105],["Seaborgiyum",106],["Bohriyum",107], 
["Hassiyum",108],["Meitneriyum",109],
["Darmstadtiyum",110],["Röntgenyum",111],["Kopernikyum",112], 
["Nihonyum",113],["Flerovyum",114],["Moscovyum",115],
["Livermoryum",116],["Tennessine",117],["Oganesson",118],["None","None"], 
["None","None"]]






dic = dict(zip(elements_symbols,elements_information))

def degistir():
pass

B = []

for i in elements_symbols:
    B.append(Button(text=i, width=7, height=3, relief=RAISED, bg="white", 
    command=degistir))

sayac = 0

for i in range(6):
    for j in range(20):
        B[sayac].place(x=60 +0.8*j*80,y=10+0.8*i*80)
        sayac +=1

metin = StringVar()
metin.set("Bilgilerini görmek istediğiniz elementin simgesine tıklayınız") 
etiket = Label(pencere, textvariable=metin, font="Times 20")
etiket.place(x=380,y=500)

mainloop()
```

Comment: Hello Baho! Please share what have you tried so far

Comment: I added what I did, thanks for reminding

Comment: No no, when you can add code as text then why adding code as images, it is bad practice because we can't copy your and test it :(

Comment: I use this platform for the first time,
thanks for your feedback i will be more careful next time

Comment: @Bonno hope my answer is what you are looking for. if you need extra help let me know

Answer (score 0):

try using a dictionary for the information

`elements = {'H':{'name':'Hydrogen', 'mass':float(1.008)}, 'HE':[]}`

and here is some code to update text boxes

```
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()
var = StringVar()`enter code here`
label = Label( root, textvariable=var, relief=RAISED )

var.set("Hey!? How are you doing?")

def Update_Text(element_name):
    var.set(elements[element_name]['name'])

label.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

you can use partial to send data through a button

`from functools import partial`

`Tkinter.Button(root, text ="Hello", command=partial(Update_Text,'H'))`

you could also use your for loop

```
for i in elements_symbols:
    Button(text=i, width=7, height=3, relief=RAISED, bg="white", 
    command=partial(Update_Text,i)))
```

dont forget to .place/.grid/.pack your button. try and do this in the same for loop by using `+=`

let me know if you need more help